# Emailing Pandas df resulting into poor formating

Tags: python, pandas

I wish to email a pandas df as html to a group. Below is my code. This code works but, the formatting is very poor. Is there any method/function to beautify the output?

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from smtplib import SMTP
 
 
recipients = ['email@email.com'] 
emaillist = [elem.strip().split(',') for elem in recipients]
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = "Subject"
msg['From'] = 'email@email.com'
  
df = pd.read_html(url)
  
#Formats the table on the IDLE -> Python Shell display
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
 
message = df.sort_values(by='Employed On',ascending=False).to_string(index=False)
 
#print(message)
 
html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    {0}
  </body>
</html>
""".format(message)
 
part1 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
msg.attach(part1)
 
server = smtplib.SMTP("**credentials like IP or Server Name or Port**")
server.sendmail(msg['From'], emaillist , msg.as_string())
```

EDIT:
Ideally, for df:

```
pd.DataFrame({
    'a': np.random.random(3),
    'b': np.random.random(3),
    'c': np.random.random(3),
})
```

I would like it to display like this

```
       a         b         c
 0.519543  0.624896  0.826649
 0.801702  0.596582  0.868678
 0.027843  0.764078  0.807556
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly export the dataframe to html:

```
pd.DataFrame({
    'a': np.random.random(3),
    'b': np.random.random(3),
    'c': np.random.random(3),
}).to_html()
```

this produces:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>a</th>
      <th>b</th>
      <th>c</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>0.950004</td>
      <td>0.308753</td>
      <td>0.678557</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>0.760626</td>
      <td>0.357484</td>
      <td>0.789428</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>0.748318</td>
      <td>0.735334</td>
      <td>0.703516</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```